# how to make sidebar disappear when clicking outside?

Tags: javascript, html

```
var mySidebar = document.getElementById("mySidebar");
  
  function s4_open() {
    if (mySidebar.style.display === 'block') {
      mySidebar.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      mySidebar.style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
```

Comment: focus selector might be a good start for your answer. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp

Answer (score -2):

Edit your js code to following

```js
$('#menu-button').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#hide-menu').toggleClass('show-menu');
});

$('#hide-menu').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$('body,html').click(function(e){
   $('#hide-menu').removeClass('show-menu');
});
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: Where do you see that they are using jQuery?